# Understanding ! operator in typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I'm very new to typescript and I'm trying to learn the language.

I'm reading through a component and I see this:

```
interface FilterRowProps {
  cannotRemove: boolean
  filterName?: string
}

const field = getField(demo.fields)(filterName!)
```

**Questions:**

- This made me think, What is `!` in typescript signified for?
- What happens if it's not passed (optional parameter?) does it throw an error or does it not do anything?
- Does it make sense to make argument optional and use `!` inside component?

Since `filterName` props is optional, what does `filterName!` signify?

Can someone explain? Super confused.

Comment: It's a [Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I don't understand why people are downvoting when a relevant context (with code) was provided. Very demotivating. I genuinely want to know if having an optional argument and non-null assertion operator in the same component makes sense

Comment: It's meant to be used to suppress warnings about a variable not being checked for `null` or `undefined` when you know that it will never be `null` but the compiler isn't able to conclude that from a static analysis.

Comment: @TechnoCorner I don't think there's really enough context to give you a really good "answer". Questions 1 and 2 are pretty low effort and could be answered with a little bit of research on your end. Nicholas Tower gives about as good of a possible "answer" to question 3, but it's still pretty vague because the example code isn't much more than "an example of bad typescript" on it's own.

Comment: I agree that the official documentation is already pretty clear about what `!` does and it should be the go-to resource for an explanation. The only thing that it maybe lacks is a real-world example of code where its usage is indicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `!` is the [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator). It tells typescript "i know this looks like it might be `null`/`undefined`, but trust me, it's not". This is occasionally needed in cases where typescript can't figure out that your code eliminates the possibility of a null or undefined.

But be aware that like any type assertion, you are telling typescript not to check your work. If you use it, and it actually *can* be `null`/`undefined`, typescript will not alert you to this fact, and you may get an error at runtime.

In short: you should rarely use this. Most of the time, if the types lead typescript to deduce that it might be `undefined`, then it's probably right. You should then write code to deal with the `undefined`.

Comment: This is a great answer. Thank you!